# Escape characters interpreted as array in SAS

Tags: sas

I am using SAS university edition.

I want to have a variable named "Age(years)" instead of "Age_years" for the following data set. I understand that "()" will be interpreted as array, while I need this to be a part of the variable.

```
data data;
  input Name $ Age_years Gender $;
  datalines;
    Dino 6 male
    Rita 5 female
    Aurora 6 female
    Joko 7 male
  ;
run;
```

The exact error when I am accessing the following line is " ERROR: Undeclared array referenced: Age.
ERROR: Variable Age has not been declared as an array."

```
 data data;
  set data;
  Age(years)=Age_years;
 run;
```

I have checked for possibility of escaping this bracket characters so that it won't be interpreted as array as in here : [Special Characters in SAS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6096227/special-characters-in-sas) however the % symbol does not help to escape the () characters. How can I do this in SAS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could call that 'n' a modifier. There are a few you can append to the end of a quoted literal to specify how SAS should treat it:

`'my variable'n` will be treated as a variable called 'my variable'

`'14AUG2017'd` will be treated as a number representing today's date

`'14AUG2017:09:53:00'dt` will be treated as a number representing today's date and time

`'49'x` will be treated as the letter A, here specified by its hexadecimal value.

...and others I may have forgotten.

Note that it is not considered good practice to use non SAS-valid names.

EDIT: [link to SAS support](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lrcon/62955/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a000780334.htm#a002154623)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I missed some hints from other SO links. 
[SAS: how to use the table column with special character $](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32108652/sas-how-to-use-the-table-column-with-special-character?rq=1)

How I solved this is with the following

```
option validvarname=any;
data data;
'Age(years)'n = Age_years;
run
```

Thing is I do not understand what does "n" above actually means, because if I remove it, Age(years) will mean string.